# Perl use Package - AH01215: Undefined subroutine

Tags: perl

I'm using the package **URI::Escape**. Usually, I can call the functions directly by naming it, e.g. uri_unescape('some text') but actual I'm getting AH01215: Undefined subroutine &MyFunctions::uri_unescape called at ...

This happens in an own package ('MyFunctions') of me. I got the use URI::Escape line. When I use &URI::Escape::uri_unescape it seems to work fine. But I just don't get why it is looking for this subroutine in my package...

Can someone explain it to me? Is there any way to solve this? I really don't wanna write this whole package-name::funktion every time I call this function :/

Comment: Is the `use URI::Escape` line located after the `package MyFunctions` line?

Comment: No before. I'm always importing CPAN-Packages first, then use lib "/my/path" and importing my routines...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The subroutines are imported into the current namespace. You have to put the `use` line after the `package` declaration:

```
package MyFunctions;
use URI::Escape;
```

Otherwise, the functions are imported into the previous namespace, which is probably `main` in your case (you can verify by running `main::uri_unescape()`.

Comment: Souns good. I'll give it a try after lunch. Thanks in advice.